# enlaces <a> no funcionan en emails en iphone y outlook con phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail, iphone, outlook

He desarrollado un sistema de mailing para una pagina php con phpmailer y estamos teniendo problemas con los enlaces, por alguna razón los  en Gmail y en la aplicación de Android de Gmail se ven correctamente, pero haciendo pruebas con mi cuenta de hotmail (outlook.live) y con una cuenta de Gmail pero abierta desde un Iphone con la aplicación de correo el "AQUI" en lugar de ser un enlace se ve tal que así en forma de string:

"Para activar la newsletter pulsa [dominio.com/pagina.php?id=35]AQUI."

el código es el siguiente:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errores y mensajes, 2 = sólo mensajes
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // auth habilitada
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // transferencia segura REQUERIDA para Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->Username = "email";
$mail->Password = "pass";
$mail->SetFrom('email');
$mail->FromName = 'nombre';
$mail->AddAddress($mailto);
$mail->WordWrap=50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $mailsubject;
$message = 'Para acceder a la calculadora pulsa <a href="dominio.com/pagina.php?id='.$id.'" target="_blank">AQUI</a>.';
$mail->Body = $message;
$exito = $mail->Send();
```

si me ocurriera con todos los email podría empezar por alguna parte pero siendo asi de selectivo no encuentro nada por la red

Comment: Prueba poniendole el protocolo en el `href`, ya sea `http://` o `https://`, solo por probar a ver (y para dejarlo bien... sin protocolo y desde un mail no es lo mismo que si fuera una página web donde ya estás en un protocolo determinado cuando clicas en un enlace de esos que no tienen).

Comment: Jamás se me hubiese ocurrido, es algo que tengo tan interiorizado que no dudaba de que eso no fuera un problema, en outlook solucionado, ahora tengo que esperar al compañero para probarlo en apple, muchas gracias

Comment: ah si?  jolin, si que he tenido punteria pues :-)   Pues lo voy a dejar como respuesta y cuando verifiques lo del apple recuerda marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa.  No es algo que sea facil de encontrar por la red, tal como tu has dicho :-)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo el protocolo en el `href`, ya sea `http://` o `https://`.

Sin protocolo y desde un mail no es lo mismo que si fuera una página web donde ya estás en un protocolo determinado cuando clicas en un enlace de esos que no tienen protocolo, pues recoge el protocolo actual donde estás navegando en ese momento.

Es decir, en lugar de esto:

```
$message = 'Para acceder a la calculadora pulsa <a href="dominio.com/pagina.php?id='.$id.'" target="_blank">AQUI</a>.';
```

déjalo así:

```
$message = 'Para acceder a la calculadora pulsa <a href="https://dominio.com/pagina.php?id='.$id.'" target="_blank">AQUI</a>.';
```

También se me ocurre que desde un webmail quizás tambien hubiera funcionado poniendo tan solo las dos barras, sin protocolo, para que intente interpretarlo basándose en el protocolo del webmail, pero bueno, voto por ponerlo completo igualmente :-)